# При вызове метода с запросом, переходит сразу в метод интерфейса

Tags: android, kotlin, интерфейс, rxjava, retrofit2

Задача: Отправить запрос на сервер с данными и принять ответ.

API интерфейс:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/reg")
    fun registration(@Field("name") name: String,
                              @Field("phone") phone: String,
                              @Field("email") email: String,
                              @Field("password") password: String,
                              @Field("referer") referer: String,
                              @Field("promo") promo: String,
                              @Field("code") deviceId: String): Observable<Response<UserWithKeys>>
```

CallBack для этого запроса:

```
interface AuthorizationCallBack{
        fun userWithKeyCallBack(userWithKeys: UserWithKeys)
        fun errorCallBack(error: String)
    }
```

Запрос в репозитории:

```
fun registration(name: String, phone: String, email: String, password: String, referer: String, promo: String, deviceId: String,
                     autorizationCallBack: AuthorizCallB, failCallBack: FailCallBack){
        val s = serverApi.registration(name, phone, email, password, referer, promo, deviceId)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({if (it.isSuccessful)
                    autorizationCallBack.userWithKeyCallBack(it.body()!!)
                }, {
                    failCallBack.throwableCallBack(it)
                })
    }
```

Запрос в логике Presenter

```
fun registrationNewUser(name: String, phone: String, email: String, pass: String,
                            referer: String, promo: String, myDeviceId: String) {

        val disposable = repositoryApi.registration(name, phone, email, pass, referer, promo, myDeviceId, object : AuthorizCallB {
            override fun userWithKeyCallBack(userWithKeys: UserWithKeys) {
                if (userWithKeys.publickey!=""){
                    responseeRegistrationNewUser(userWithKeys)
                    Log.i("Loog", "RegistrationFragmentProvider reg - ${userWithKeys!!.id}")
                }
                else
                    Log.i("Loog", "RegistrationFragmentProvider reg - null")
            }

            override fun errorCallBack(error: String) {
                showErrorMessage(error)
            }
        }, object : FailCallBack {
            override fun throwableCallBack(throwable: Throwable) {
                showErrorMessage(throwable.message!!)
                BugReport().sendBugInfo(throwable.message.toString(), "RegistrationFragmentProvider.registrationNewUser.throwableCallBack")
            }
        })

    }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при вызове метода "registrationNewUser(...)" сразу отрабатывает "responseeRegistrationNewUser" в теле интерфейса, и потом приходит ответ с сервера, метод "responseeRegistrationNewUser" не отрабатывает, срабатывает только лог.

Логи:

```
I/Loog: registrationNewUser
I/Loog: responseRegistrationNewUser
I/Loog: RegistrationFragmentProvider reg - 3119
```

Класс UserWithKeys:

```
class UserWithKeys(var id: Int, var name: String, var phone: String, val email: String, val sum: Int, val score: Int,
                   var level: Int, var publickey: String, var privatekey: String, var refererLink: String, var favorites: Array<Int>)
```

Так же использую Dagger2
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вынесите вызов метода subscribe в презентер, а репозиторий пускай возвращает Observable<>, по надобности обработайте возвращаемое значение через flatMap в репозитории

Comment: Метод `responseeRegistrationNewUser()` тоже покажите. Пока проблему вообще не вижу.

Comment: Невнимательность... В данном случае все работает!)